# Ruby with sinatra and activerecord mysql db duplicate error not getting raised as exception

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am creating a simple user registration functionality and making user input firstname, lastname and email. Email field should be unique for all users. I have given this constraint in db. In code though, when a row with duplicate email is input, it does not create a row in db but does not raise any exception too. I am stuck on how to show error to user.

```
My code:
table creation script:
CREATE TABLE customers (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), firstname VARCHAR(25), lastname VARCHAR(25), email VARCHAR(50), UNIQUE KEY(email), password VARCHAR(50));


def self.create_new(params)
    begin
      customer = Customer.create!(:firstname=>params[:firstname], :lastname => params[:lastname], :email => params[:email], :password => params[:password])
      return {:success => true, :message => "success", :id => customer.id }
    rescue => e
      return {:success => false, :message => e.message}
    end
  end
```

Should I add a uniqueness validation at model level to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added db backed validation, which is working. Now you should add explicit validation in your model (as you've suggested), so that it throws an exception saying what is wrong.

So adding `validates :email, uniqueness: true` to the model would do what you expect.

Comment: you could use it for sure, but according to rails styles guide, it is more conventional to write as I've shown: (https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i guess `validates :email, presence: true` will just check for the presence of email and what the question is asking for the validation of uniqueness[ not presence ]. am i missing something? i guess not.

Comment: ooo, sure-sure, it should be`uniqueness`, just a typo :) let me edit the answer